Exporting complete Solutions from Power Platform to Repos on AzureDevOps with Pipelines
The Tasks in the pipeline
The compare function when exporting solution packages with pipeline
The compare function when exporting only the app (with personal access tokens) instead of the full solution
I export a solution package from powerplatform to Repos on AzureDevOps. For this I am using pipelines. I've already put a solution in the main branch. Now I've made some changes in the app on power platform, and exported the app with the changes (the full solution package) to a branch on Repos.
The issue I encounter is that I don't clearly get to see the changes and the difference between the app in main and the app in the branch.
When I do this via another route, by using personal access tokens etc and uploading only the app (not the complete solution package) to repos, I do get to see the exact differences between the apps, showing which exact changes are made in the newer version of the app. See screenshots.
I want to do version control, and whenever someone makes changes I want to be able to compare and approve before pushing to production.
I've watched all the youtube videos an read through all the documentations, but it seems like that no one has ever encounterd this issue?? Every youtube video, every guide on google stops at the 'upload and visible on repos'-stage. None of them continue to the next step and do the actual version comparison.
Kind Regards.

HI @KamalShibaz, Have you got a check to test my PowerShell script below to check and upload the unpacked solution? Hope it helps resolve the query in this post. Thx for your time and sharing.

It was not shared what git commands that your pipeline ran to push the unpacked Power App solution to Azure Repos, but based on your description, the workflow below may help you to Export solution from your Power App Environment -> Unpack the solution -> Push the extracted contents to the pipeline source repo. Here are the brief steps for your reference.

Make sure the solution is extracted to $(Build.SourcesDiretory), which is the path on the pipeline agent machine and where the pipeline checks out the source code from the remote repo;


To use the $(System.AccessToken) of the pipeline service account as the authentication of the git commands in the PowerShell script, we need to first check Allow scripts to access the OAuth token option of the Agent job and grant Contribute permission for the pipeline service account to push to source repo;


Inline PowerShell script


Write-Host "================1. Show contents in Build.SourcesDirectory: ================"
tree $(Build.SourcesDirectory) /F /A

Write-Host "================2. Push the exported solutions to source repo: ================"
git config --global user.email “$(Build.RequestedForEmail)”
git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
git checkout -b $(Build.SourceBranchName)
git add .
git commit -m "Solution exported by $(Build.DefinitionName) in build $(Build.BuildId)"
git push origin $(Build.SourceBranchName)




If you would simply use the repo as a temporary storage to keep the downloaded solutions and extracted contents, you may also consider publishing the files as pipeline artifacts;



The pipeline and its script have used several pipeline predefined variables, please take reference to this document to help understand the workflow.
